# Why does compilation fail with "not found: value Users"?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I want to retrieve a row from my default database `postgres`. I have table "Users" defined already.

**conf/application.conf**

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5234/postgres"
db.default.user="postgres"
db.default.password=""
```

**controllers/Application.scala**

```
package controllers

import models.{UsersDatabase, Users}
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action { 
    Ok(views.html.index(UsersDatabase.getAll))
  }
}
```

**models/Users.scala**

```
package models

import java.sql.Date
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.DB
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

case class User(
    id: Int,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    full_name: String,
    email: String,
    gender: String,
    dob: Date,
    joined_date: Date
)

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "Users") {

    def id = column[Int]("id")
    def username = column[String]("username", O.PrimaryKey)
    def password = column[String]("password")
    def full_name = column[String]("full_name")
    def email = column[String]("email")
    def gender = column[String]("gender")
    def dob = column[Date]("dob")
    def joined_date = column[Date]("joined_date")
    def * = (id, username, password, full_name, email, gender, dob, joined_date) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}

object UsersDatabase {

    def getAll: List[User] = {
        Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource()) withSession {
            Query(Users).list
        }
    }
}
```

While accessing `http://localhost:9000/` it gives compilation error:

```
[error] .../app/models/Users.scala:36: not found: value Users
[error]             Query(Users).list
[error]                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

How to resolve this error and access data properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compilation error message says it all - there's no value `Users` to use in the scope.

Change the object `UsersDatabase` to look as follows:

```
object UsersDatabase {

    val users = TableQuery[Users]

    def getAll: List[User] = {
        Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource()) withSession { implicit session =>
            users.list
        }
    }
}
```

And the error goes away since you're using the local `val users` to list users in the database.

As described in [Querying](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/queries.html#querying) in the official documentation of Slick `session` val is an implicit value of [list](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/#scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker) (as `final def list(implicit session: SessionDef): List[R]`), and hence `implicit session` in the block:

> All methods that execute a query take an implicit Session value. Of
>   course, you can also pass a session explicitly if you prefer:
>
> ```
> val l = q.list(session)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your great support, really appreciated. But running this giving me further error

`[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.Result
[error]  required: slick.driver.PostgresDriver.backend.Session => play.api.mvc.Result
[error]     (which expands to)  slick.driver.PostgresDriver.backend.SessionDef => play.api.mvc.Result
[error]                         Ok(views.html.index(UsersDatabase.getAll))
[error]                           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] application -`

index.scala.html
`@(users: List[User])

<h1>Compiled</h1>`

Comment: What was it? I'd like to add it to the answer.

Comment: It was mine silly mistake, again wrapping result with database session in controller:
def index = Action { 
Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource()) withSession { ...
    Ok(views.html.index(UsersDatabase.getAll))
}
  }

It was not done when I asked this question. Your edits and answer is absolutely right.